# Does anyone know how to bound decaying exponential series of the form $\exp(\sum_{k = i + 1}^n-C/(k+1))$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Consider a series with the form,

$$\exp(\sum_{k = i + 1}^n -C/(k+1))$$

where $C > 0$ is some constant and $n, i$ are integers with the assumption $n > i+1$

I wish to find some type upper-bound for this series, i.e., in $O(1/k^m)$ for some $m$. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wish to estimate $\sum_{k=n+1}^N \frac{1}{k+1}$. The integral test tells you that this sequence is lower bounded by $\log\left(\frac{N+1}{n+2}\right)$. Thus, your expression is upper bounded by
$$\left(\frac{N+1}{n+2}\right)^{-C}.$$